# Can any one please let me know that where exactly Python-Pickle used and give me one great example to understand

Tags: python, pickle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pickle Python Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106178/pickle-python-serialization)

Hi I am new to python. Please explain where exactly we will use pickle and give me one clear example to understand...it would be great if you could do this....

Answer (score 1):

You will come to know when you really want to serialize the data, store it and reuse it.
Suppose in a particular python script, you decide to create a graph, usually the graph can be best stored as a dictionary of lists. Now, you can store them some form of a database or a flat file, in which case you would have to reconstruct the data structure when you read it back. Suppose, you think of having an ability to store the data-stucture and its contents in form and get back the exact data-structure and use it from the point go. There you have pickle coming in handy. This is very useful when you want to send your data(-structure) over the network for another program to consume. Check this simple [example here](http://effbot.org/librarybook/pickle.htm) and [some documentation.](http://effbot.org/pylib/pickle.htm)